# How to get the correct left position of a shape within a group when using python-pptx?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I am parsing a simple PowerPoint with three shapes. One shape is visibly to the left of the two other. But not when comparing it using python-pptx. The right side of that left shape (shape.left+shape.width) has a higher value than one of the other shapes left side (shape.left). The python-pptx result seem to indicate the right-hand shape starts within the left-hand shapes border. This seem to be caused by the group shape the right-hand shape is within.

What is the proper code to compare correctly that the right-hand shapes left side in fact is to the right of the left-hand shape?

I have tried removing the group, and then comparisons show expected values. I have tried creating new group shapes with shapes within, and again, they show expected values. However, the linked PowerPoint file at www.mibnet.se/LeftBoxIssue.pptx is an example where the group shape affects the normal result. When running the code, I do not know how the shapes were created. I need a generic way to test this special case correctly.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE_TYPE

strStartPowerPoint=r".\LeftBoxIssue.pptx"
prs=Presentation(strStartPowerPoint)
slide=prs.slides[0]
for shpShape in slide.shapes:
    if shpShape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.GROUP:
        print(shpShape.shapes[0].text+
             " has   Left="+str(shpShape.shapes[0].left)+
             " and right="+
             str(shpShape.shapes[0].left+shpShape.shapes[0].width))
    else:
        print(shpShape.text+" has Left="+str(shpShape.left)+
             " and right="+str(shpShape.left+shpShape.width))
```

I expect the right hand shape to have its "left" value greater than the left-hand shapes "right" value. But instead, it prints a smaller value:

```
Left has Left=160326 and right=6254527
Right has Left=3291751 and right=3846370
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to start in understanding this is inspecting the group-shape XML:

```
print(group_shape._element.xml)
```

There you will find a child element that looks like this:

```
<p:grpSpPr>
  <a:xfrm>
    <a:off x="3347864" y="2204864"/>
    <a:ext cx="3506688" cy="2930624"/>
    <a:chOff x="3347864" y="2204864"/>
    <a:chExt cx="3506688" cy="2930624"/>
  </a:xfrm>
</p:grpSpPr>
```

The `<a:chOff>` element represents the "child-offset" of shapes within the group. In this case, which is typical of shapes grouped in `python-pptx`, note that the `a:chOff` values are exactly the same as the `a:off` values, which represent the top-left corner of the group-shape.

Using these two sets of values, you can calculate some interesting positions.

1. **Absolute position of child shapes.** This is child `a:off` plus group `a:off` minus group `a:chOff`.
2. **Relative position of child shapes** (to the group-shape origin). This is child `a:off` minus group `a:chOff`.

You can get these extra child-offset values from the group with:

```
chOff = group_shape._element.xpath("./p:grpSpPr/a:xfrm/a:chOff")[0]
chOff_x = int(chOff["x"])
chOff_y = int(chOff["y"])
```

These values are in *English Metric Units* (EMU) which are described here along with how you might conveniently manipulate them:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/autoshapes.html#understanding-english-metric-units

`python-pptx` always uses a child offset equal to the group shape position (`a:off`) because that is convenient. Other packages may use other group-shape offsets that are more convenient to their purposes. For example, if you were to *move* a group, you could accomplish that by changing `a:off` in the group only, without having to visit and update each of the child shape positions.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out. Would that affect also a a group shape inside a group shape? Meaning I need to first go to the top group shape and apply the same adjustments through the chain to get the total offset?

Comment: I expect so. In its role as a child shape, a group shape is like any other shape that might be inside an enclosing group.

Comment: Ok, I tested it. My interpretation of your answer, adjusted since chOff["x"] did not work is as follows: "True left" for shape=shpShape.left+group_shape._element.xpath("./p:grpSpPr/a:xfrm/a:off")[0].x+group_shape._element.xpath("./p:grpSpPr/a:xfrm/a:chOff")[0].x Is this in line with your statement?

Comment: Ok, yeah, it's been a while since I've used `lxml` native access, it looks like the two ways to get an attribute from an `lxml.etree._Element` object are like `chOff.get("x")` and `chOff.attrib["x"]`. The `chOff.x` attribute works only because that element is "wrapped" by a `python-pptx` `oxml` object, so won't work will all elements when you're digging down past the API-support in the XML. But it's definitely a nice compact version in this case which even does type conversion to an `Emu` object for you and so on for you (the lxml versions always return str).